# Whats the difference between Facebook Php API and oAuth Authentication?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, oauth

As the title of the question suggests; whats the difference between Facebook Php API and oAuth Authentication?

It seems there are two methods for authentication wtih Facebook. One is the oAuth 2.0 which can be seen [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). The other one is the [Facebook PHP API](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503) (which also uses oAuth since V3)

Is there a difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a big difference. oAuth is just one thing the PHP API can do. The PHP API can get stats, friends list, post to walls, send request, etc. Of course, most things can't be done with the PHP API until you authentication, using oAuth.

One way to think of it is that oAuth is the login, PHP API is how you interact with Facebook.